# How to pass value from execute to another command using intern and leadfoot

Tags: typescript, intern, leadfoot

Basically I'm trying to resize the screen to full height and width using values returned from the execute function. I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the values from the execute function to my resize function and was hoping someone could take a look at my code and show me where I'm going wrong? when I check saucelabs command executions I don't see the resize command getting fired before the screenshot. So I'm not certain exactly where the breakdown is (whether the size isn't being passed correctly or the timing is incorrect. When I hardcode the size instead of trying to get it from execute, it works perfectly.
Thank you!!

```
    registerSuite('homepage', {
  'homepage'() { 
    return this.remote.get('myurl') 
      .setWindowPosition(0,0)
      .maximizeWindow() 
      .execute(() => [
        document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight
      ])
      .then(([width, height]) => { return helpers.resizeWindow(width, height) }) 
      .takeScreenshot() 
      .then(assertVisuals(this, { missingBaseline: 'snapshot', regenerateBaselines: true }) );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this by doing 2 things. I removed the helper.resizeWindow and used the regular command.resizeWindow, and instead of embedding it within the callback function, i just placed it there without the curly braces and without a return statement. I'm unsure why this syntax works and the other did not.

```
registerSuite('homepage', {
    'homepage'() {
            return this.remote.get('mypage')
            .setWindowPosition(0,0)
            .maximizeWindow()
            .execute(() => [document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollHeight])
            .then(([width, height]) => this.remote.setWindowSize(width, height))
            .takeScreenshot()
            .then(
                assertVisuals(this, {
                    missingBaseline: 'snapshot',
                    regenerateBaselines: true
                })
            );
    }
});
```